# control robot via internet

Tags: asp.net, .net, robotics

i have robot and want to control it via internet using radio wave .. but still i dont know the best language to do that . with the need to build scure site to insure not any body can use it . i expect for site asp with c# but what is the language i'll need it to control from sender device to the recipt robot . also need to live video transfer to the site from robot camera............
soory for bothering .....i know it may wrong but i'm beginner

and thanks for all who read or try to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be best to narrow down your choice of technologies before choosing a programming language. Robotics control can be a very complex topic, and there are many approaches to solving the same problem.

Having said that, with the components you've listed:

- Secure internet interface
- RF communication to an autonomous robot
- Embedded robot control software
- Video processing, compression and decompression
- Display of video to internet visitors

I would guess that your complete solution would involve at least two or three different programming languages, depending on application and environment.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth taking a look at [Microsoft Robotics Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/robotics/default.aspx) to give you an exampleof a framework you can work with. Generally all the various controllers etc "talk" different languages so you use something like robotics studio to tie them all together so you can talk to them all in a common way.

It's a hell of a tall order for a beginner though, there's far more to think about than picking a language :-)